# Set header to listview from layout

Tags: android, header, android-listview

everybody!

I got such situation: I have a layout with some views and a listView. A question is: is it possible to take those views (from the layout where listview is situated) and set them as a header to this listview?

By now I tried:

```
LinearLayout header = (LinearLayout)getView().findViewById(R.id.header);
listView.addHeaderView(header, null, true);
```

This gives me an error:

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18913): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams
    at android.widget.ListView.clearRecycledState(ListView.java:553)
    at android.widget.ListView.resetList(ListView.java:539)
    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1477)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1407)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7314)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1130)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1047)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7314)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7314)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:912)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7314)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:912)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7314)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7314)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1130)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1047)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7314)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7314)
    at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1180)
    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1900)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: like,you want to put all views on top of listview as if they are a header as one? or you want to put them at various places in a listview,diving it into parts?

Comment: there is a method in a listview listView.addHeaderView(view,data,isSelectable). I want to take my views, which are now in the same layout with a listView and are grouped in a LinearLayout, and add them as this list header

Comment: then what is the problem ? have you tried anything to meet your needs?

Comment: Of course i had. Look through the initial post.